# How can I start image viewer feh to start in fullscreen, zoom pictures to 100%, and always show them from the top left corner, not vertical centered?

Tags: jpeg

I would like to watch images, which are quite tall, image height are much larger, then screen height. I can easily scroll down the image in feh by Alt+Down_arrow.
To achieve this I start feh with options:

```
feh --zoom 100 -F *.jpg
```

The problem is, that all images is centered on the screen, and I have to scroll the up, and then down, instead of scrolling them only downwards, to see the parts which don't fit in the screen.

Unfortunately I can't find any option to tell feh to position the images by their top left corner into the screen's top left corner, or maybe horizontally centered, but aligning the upper side of the image to the upper side of the screen.

How can I start image viewer feh to start in fullscreen, zoom pictures to 100%, and always show them from the top left corner, not centered?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to be documented yet, but the source code reveals that there is an `--offset` option, so to get images to load in the top left corner, you could add this:

```
--offset +0+0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I might suggest, `feh` is a basic, lightweight image viewer which does not do very much. `display` from the `imagemagick` package is just as lightweight, but it's also a functional viewer and basic editor.

Image viewers are trivial programs to begin with. Making one that is super lightweight is usually unnecessary. But, if your running Linux on a Kindle, or an embedded system, it might make sense.

I welcome you to give `display` a try. You operate it by `display <path to images>/*.jpg` Use whichever extension your files have. It is extremely fast, and the quality is unsurpassable.

It starts the way you have requested. But that is configurable. The editing features are available, but you'll never see them unless you want to.